# filter IPaddress from list

Tags: python, filter, strip

I am a newbie to python I managed to pull data from an excel sheet using xlrd and put into a list and remove all white/empty spaces

I need to pull out the IP addresses from the list or remove all text. I have looked at strip regex and the module IP address but just seem overwhelmed, please help me find a solution.

```
ipList = ['Device name:', 'Management IPs:', 'Virtual Server IP', '10.100.33.131 (Prod)', '10.100.33.132 (Prod)', '10.100.33.133 (Prod)', '10.100.33.134 (Prod)', '10.100.33.148 (QA)', '10.100.33.149 (QA)', '10.100.33.150 (QA)', 'Scripted / HTTP Health check details', 'Name', 'iRule requirements']
#
```

Comment: Can you post your expected output as well as some code of what you have tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex to extract the IP from the list.

```
import re

ipList = ['Device name:', 'Management IPs:', 'Virtual Server IP', '10.100.33.131 (Prod)', '10.100.33.132 (Prod)', '10.100.33.133 (Prod)', '10.100.33.134 (Prod)', '10.100.33.148 (QA)', '10.100.33.149 (QA)', '10.100.33.150 (QA)', 'Scripted / HTTP Health check details', 'Name', 'iRule requirements']
IP = []
for element in ipList:
    ip = re.findall( r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', element)
    if len(ip) > 0:
        IP.append(ip)
print IP
```

Comment: Thanks that exactly what i needed

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like:

```
import re 
pat=re.compile(r'''\b((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
    (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
    (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.
    (25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?))\b''', re.X)

>>> [m.group(1) for s in ipList for m in pat.finditer(s)]
['10.100.33.131', '10.100.33.132', '10.100.33.133', '10.100.33.134', '10.100.33.148', '10.100.33.149', '10.100.33.150']
```

Uses the regex from [HERE](http://www.regular-expressions.info/ip.html)

If you don't need to validate that they look like good IP4 addresses, you can shorten the regex to:

```
>>> pat=re.compile(r'\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b')  
>>> [m.group(0) for s in ipList for m in pat.finditer(s)]
['10.100.33.131', '10.100.33.132', '10.100.33.133', '10.100.33.134', '10.100.33.148', '10.100.33.149', '10.100.33.150']
```

A pure Python filter solution might be something like:

```
>>> filter(None, [''.join([c for c in s if c in '0123456789.']) for s in  ipList])
['10.100.33.131', '10.100.33.132', '10.100.33.133', '10.100.33.134', '10.100.33.148', '10.100.33.149', '10.100.33.150']
```

Comment: Thanks for your help